# How do I use an item in Odin Sphere?

Tags: odin-sphere

So, I can eat food to regain health.

I press R2 to bring up the inventory, highlight a mulberry and hit X. That just lets me move it around. No other button works.

How do I eat the mulberry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odin's Sphere has two inventories. Pressing R2 brings up an inventory which you can only use to manage your items. To use them you have to press circle.